# How to import the data in a local file into an array for use in javascript?

Tags: javascript, file, visual-studio-code

I have been reading through these forums for hours upon hours, and I have still not been able to find a forum that asks this question and the answers actually work for me.

I am trying to create an application for my friends that basically takes in a huge huge list of different attributes and randomly creates an item out of them. I was trying to learn javascript at the time, and because my friend doesn't have any compilers or text editors installed, the language seemed like a really convenient way to send him a folder and allow him to run it in his browser.

The issue is, I have this huge list of attributes, and I want to store them in an array. My goal was to place all of these attributes in a .txt file, and somehow do like a

```
let data = readFile('./attributes.txt');
```

type thing. I do not have any crazy libraries installed, I am not doing any server work or needing the user to even know that the file exists, it was just meant to be a way to store the data of my array in a less disgusting manner and keep my .js file cleaner and easier to understand. Is this even possible? All the other posts I have seen have been using libraries I can't get to work or making the user select the file themselves or things of that nature.

Any help would mean the world, thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not quite sure how huge *huge* is in this context, but assuming it's nothing too crazy and you're in a node environment, the following solution will probably do what you are looking for.

I am assuming a plain text file, where every attribute is on a new line.
As a side note, if we are talking about seriously massive files, the following solution may not be too performant.

Feel free to let me know if you need any more help, or if something is unclear.

```javascript
// Read the file and convert it into an array
const fs = require("fs");
const contents = fs.readFileSync("attributes.txt");
const arr = contents.split("\n");

// Pick a random element from said array, and log it
const randomElement = arr[Math.floor(Math.random() * arr.length)];
console.log(randomElement);
```

Comment: Just realised you are looking for something in a browser environment. This does raise a few more questions. In order to load in a file, you will need some form of a webserver, as your browser will not allow you to load local files through an XHR.
However, in order to do so, you'd probably have to install node anyway, so you might want to consider going with this approach regardless?

Comment: Hello! Thanks for giving me this info. I have a couple questions though. I tried to install node, and then inside my project I ran npm init, npm install express and npm install. Those were the commands I saw to set up an npm project on the internet, but when i type "npm start" it has an error, same with "node randomItem.js" I am not sure how to get a node project running. Secondly, since I am sending this to a friend, would he have to install node, or since it installs the node requirements, like the node_modules thing, if i zipped the whole project to him, would he be able to run it somehow?

Comment: Also i am not sure how to add a picture to a comment to show you my code and errors, but if you let me know how to get them to you I would be happy to! I really appreciate the help!

Comment: Express is essentially a nice library built on top of node's http packages. It is used to  run a webserver - which you don't need. All you'd need is to install node, paste the code I wrote in a .js file, and run `node whateveryoucalledit.js`. Should do the trick :)
As for zipping it up, I'm afraid that that won't work. You can give him the javascript file, but he would still need to install node. If you need something truly portable, and simple, maybe you can get away with some shell scripts? You'd have to post a new question for that though. Let me know :)